# PythonAnywhere WSGI error

Tags: django, wsgi, pythonanywhere

in spite of my best efforts in the past weeks I've been stuck at deploying the WSGI file on Pythonanywhere while trying to set up a django framework. There are similar topics on here, but none were adoptable to my case.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/) and I get the following error message:

```
2017-03-04 22:28:05,284 :Error running WSGI application
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :  File "/var/www/iamcsongor_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :    application = get_wsgi_application()
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :  File "/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :
2017-03-04 22:28:05,285 :  File "/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :  File "/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :    self._setup(name)
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :
2017-03-04 22:28:05,286 :  File "/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
2017-03-04 22:28:05,287 :    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2017-03-04 22:28:05,287 :
2017-03-04 22:28:05,287 :  File "/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
2017-03-04 22:28:05,287 :    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

Here's my WSGI file:

```
import os

import sys

path = '/home/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/firstweb'  # use your own PythonAnywhere username here
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

I've taken a few [screenshots of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTvg7.jpg) and [Git Repo](https://github.com/iamcsongor/my-first-blog/tree/master/firstweb), if you could help, I'd be grateful.  Thanks

Comment: You haven't said what happens, what is going wrong, or what errors you see.

Comment: ugh... good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is set to "mysite", but that directory does not exist. Your settings file actually appears to be in "firstweb".

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it worked! I also had to change the working directory though... so many thing that can go wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

follow it

Start by saving your environment variables into a .env file in your project folder
You can run something like this in a Bash console, or edit the .env file directly using our "Files" tab:

```
cd ~/my-project-dir

echo "export SECRET_KEY=sekritvalue" >> .env

echo "export OTHER_SECRET=somethingelse" >> .env
```

Install python-dotenv into your virtualenv
workon my-virtualenv-name

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

## or, if you're not using a virtualenv:

```
pip3.6 install --user python-dotenv
```

## and, optionally, add it to your requirements.txt, if you're using one:

```
echo python-dotenv >> requirements.txt
```

and in wsgi file before get_wsgi_application()

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

project_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/my-project-dir')  # adjust as appropriate

load_dotenv(os.path.join(project_folder, '.env'))
```

and make changes in setting.py file and remove secret key and put

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
```

and at last, do in bash console

```
set -a; source ~/my-project-dir/.env; set +a

echo 'set -a; source ~/my-project-dir/.env; set +a' >> ~/.virtualenvs/my-project-virtualenv/bin/postactivate
```

all done remove wsgi related error