# PythonAnywhere WSGI error (solution is not found how to set is)

Tags: python, wsgi, pythonanywhere

As this answer suggested [PythonAnywhere WSGI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601777/pythonanywhere-wsgi-error)   my variable is aswell set to mysite. while my site name is project. now how can i set this variable to project on live server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer by doing

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

As It was pointing to old site name .